# Can't access "High Resolution" option in Physics Properties

Tags: physics

So, I was fooling around with beginner Blender tutorials and I was trying to learn how to set a monkey head on fire (random, I know).

Problem is, I'm supposed to check "High Resolution" in Physics Properties -> Fluid -> High Resolution, but the option doesn't even appear for me. I haven't tampered with the software in any way, is there a way to enable the option? I am using the latest version of Blender on a pretty outdated laptop, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange!

The "High Resolution" option no longer exists.

In recent updates to Blender, the fluid simulation tools (which is what handles liquids, smoke, fire, and anything else fluid) have been completely replaced. This happened in Blender 2.82. The new system uses something called MantaFlow, so any tutorials that use 2.82 or later, or specifically say MantaFlow, should be more relevant.

If you want to continue with that tutorial, I would just manually increase the resolution, which is all that the old "High Resolution" option did I believe.